# How to collapse this nested MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT num, COUNT(num) AS amt
FROM table
WHERE num IN (
    SELECT num
    FROM table
    WHERE id IN (1,2,3))
GROUP BY num
HAVING amt > 1
```

Also, how can I get

> '777' => '2'

.. instead of

> 'num' => '777'
>   'amt' => '2'

as result?

thanks

Comment: I suspect the second part of your question is PHP-related, not just SQL.

Comment: i know how in php, but i thought it could be done with mysql. thanks for editing, here is strange, terrible text editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do a `where` on a aggregate column, you have to use `having` for those.

```
SELECT t1.num, 
       COUNT(t1.num) AS amt 
FROM `table` t1
INNER JOIN `table` t2 ON (t1.num = t2.num)
WHERE t2.id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY t1.num
HAVING amt > 1
```

Comment: this make me overflow at first :) Thanks, it working good. Is any pitfalls there (highload etc.)?

Comment: @Shara, The having clause is not that expensive. It just gets evaluated late in the query, after the results of the count are known.

Comment: I'm about INNER JOIN, not about having. I make some tests and this query faster than two easy queries